# Get message ID of the message sent by my bot in python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm wondering how to get the message ID of a message being sent by a bot in discord, not a message that has already been sent.

Comment: Welcome to SO Tamari. Please can you share the code you have tried already.

Answer (score 1):

`Messageable.send` returns a `discord.Message` instance, then you can simply use the `id` attribute

```py
message = await Messageable.send("Whatever") # This can be the context, a channel, a dm channel...
message_id = message.id
```

#### Reference:

- [`Messageable.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=messageable%20send#discord.abc.Messageable.send)
- [`Message.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20id#discord.Message.id)